# Offis DCMTK's StoreSCP reset issue in Mercure's VM

Tags: virtual-machines, vagrant, operations-orchestration

When several DICOMs are sent to [mercure](https://mercure-imaging.org/docs/index.html) from an external machine (not within the VM) using the `dcmsend` command, the receiver is reset with the following error in the Receiver Logs:

`Oct 14 16:45:32 vagrant receiver.sh[13431]: E: 0006:031d TCP I/O Error (Connection reset by peer) occurred in routine: sendAssociationACTCP`

Moreover, if I attempt to send a new case after the reset, the dcmsend command execution time will last almost 1 minute due to Requesting association lasting almost a minute.

This behaviour is not seen everytime a file is sent from an external machine, but after several successfull dcmsend executions. After that, every dcmsend will last almost a minute, compared to only msec in a normal situation.

Also, if I repeat these repetitive dcmsend commands on the mercure's VM, all of them execute as expected at any moment.

I would expect when I am sending a case using the `dcmsend` command from outside the VM, to be sent within some msecs, that is what is happening if I send a case within the VM. I checked the firewall settings and this is not an issue, since connection is not blocked, but every `dcmsend` outside the VM lasts almost a minute, instead of the expected duration (msec).